# requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: <Response [200]> in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So i wrote this code for now, to get news from a specific topic from cnn right now im getting an error here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import re

serch_term = input('What News are you looking for today? ')

url = f'https://edition.cnn.com/search?q={serch_term}'
page = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

page_text = doc.find_all(class_="cnn-search__result-headline")
print(page_text)
```

But i am getting this error, i already tried a bunch of things but none of them worked for me

```
What News are you looking for today? coronavirus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Informatik\Praktik\Projekte\Python\news_automation\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 312, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

i googled already and tried a bunch of things but none of them worked
Does someone know what is wrong? So,

Comment: As i can see your mistake is this line: page = requests.get(source).text 
Becuase you are trying to make another GET request with whatever response you get back from previous call

Comment: @LentianLatifi i dont really know what you mean i dont use any get before

Comment: as you have this line: source = requests.get(url) and you use it down

Comment: @LentianLatifi im not that good at english so what do you mean what should i do?

Comment: I gave you the answer down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it myself and you should change this line of code as follows:

from: source = requests.get(url) to: page = source.text

Extra informations:

I found that u can use this search.api.cnn.io as follows and make directly into json as i wrote the code and what you need to do is extract information which you need.

```
url = f"search.api.cnn.io/content?q={serch_term}"

extra_parameters_sample_url"https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=coronavirus&sort=newest&category=business,us,politics,world,opinion,health&size=100&from=0"

source = requests.get(url).text 
json_reponse = json.loads(source)
```

Comment: Now i dont get an eror but when i print the variable page_text there are empty [] @LentianLatifi

Comment: It can be that, CNN blocks request information and it should be somehow bypassed

Comment: chnaged the code new error  what is wrong now?

Comment: Still you are sending complete HTTP response, which is wrong, it should have .text from request but somehow it is being blocked by their serevrs

Comment: @LentianLetifi fixed it but its stille empty [] like this how do i fix that?

Comment: I am researching on it and trying to make solution, but problem is cnn blocks response logic is correct.

Comment: @LentianLatii please inform me if  you found something

Answer (score 0):

As for why your original code is not working, the `page` variable is a response object but Beautiful soup is expecting HTML.

This is fixed with `doc = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")`

However, It looks like cnn is using a javascript library to render their site which would make scraping the data slightly harder as you would need to use a tool like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) to run a headless browser in order to render the content.

Following on @Lenatian's answer, the easiest way would be to call the CNN api and not have to scrape the data at all, I have updated the code to check for errors and check if there are no results from the API.
If successful it will print out a list of headlines attached to the search query.

You can also print the value of `results` to see all the other data that is sent back from the api.

```
import requests

# serch_term = input('What News are you looking for today? ')
search_term = "Corona Virus"
url = f"https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q={serch_term}"

response = requests.get(url)

if not response.ok:
  raise Exception("There was an error calling the API")

response = response.json()
results = response.get("result")

if not results:
  print("Could not find any results for your search term :(")

print([result.get("headline") for result in results])
```